# How does load balancing work for very high traffic domains?

Tags: dns, routes, load-balancing, scalability

Take Google.com for example. If it ultimately resolves to a single IP at any point of time, the packets will land on a single server. Even if all it does is send a redirect response (for transferring load other servers), it still has to be capable of handling hundreds of thousands of requests per second.

I can think of a number of non standard ways to handle this. For example the router may be programmed to load balance the packet across multiple servers. But it still means that google.com is dependent on a single physical facility as IP addresses are not portable to another location.

I was hoping internet fabric itself has some mechanism to handle such things.Multiple A records per domain is one such mechanism. But while researching this I found that google.com's DNS entry has only one A record and the IP value is different depending on which site you query it from.

How is it done? In what ways is it better and why has Google chosen to do it this way instead of having multiple A records?

Trying to lookup A record of google.com yields different results from different sites:
https://www.misk.com/tools/#dns/google.com  Resolves to 216.58.217.142
https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookupResult resolves to 172.217.9.206

Comment: "How is it done? In what ways is it better and why has Google chosen to do it this way instead of having multiple A records?" Google has multiple A-Records.

Comment: How did you check that? When I look up https://www.misk.com/tools/#dns/google.com, or https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookupResult I see just one A record

Comment: `host google.com
google.com has address 172.217.23.14
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:801::200e`

Comment: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/google.com

Comment: Also, one IP address is served from multiple locations/devices https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done using dynamic DNS/round robin DNS/ DNS load balancing.

Say your have 3 web servers at 3 different locations. When the lookup is done the DNS server will respond with a different IP for each request. Some DNS servers also allow a policy based config... wherein it can return a certain IP 70% of time and some other IP 30% of the time.

[This document provides reference on how to do this with Windows 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/app-lb).